# Formula to return row number of a word in a list with duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Shoes       20  
Pants       10  
Tshirts     15  
Socks       5  
Hats  
Shoes
```

I am looking for an excel formula that will return the row number that the word "shoes" is in. `MATCH` will work but this returns **1** when I need it to return **6** based off the fact that it is the first "shoes" that has a blank cell next to it. Is this possible? I have tried in vain to use `IF` and `ISBLANK` but to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Post your best working formula and we'll work on it.

Comment: `=(MATCH(A26,A1:A23,0)` this is what gives row 1 when I'd like it to be row 6

Comment: Thought about using helper column to make life easier?

Comment: Sorry, relatively new to this, helper column? edit: just looked it up, used this having not known it. Not sure how to implement it here

Comment: Helper column will be used to help solving the issue. Can you add a column before or after your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=MATCH(1,INDEX((($A1:$A6="Shoes")*($B1:$B6=0)),),0)
```

It uses the less commonly used ["reference from"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd#__reference_form) function of the `INDEX` function, returning an array for which both conditions ("Shoes" and zero) hold (i.e. value is 1). Finally, `MATCH` finds the 1 in that array and returns at which position.

During the evaluation the formula resolves like this:

```
=MATCH(1,INDEX(({TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE}*{FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE}),),0)
```

... and then:

```
=MATCH(1,INDEX({0,0,0,0,0,1},),0)

=MATCH(1,{0,0,0,0,0,1}, 0)

=6
```

#### Alternative with helper column

Here you would reserve a column to calculate an intermediate value. You can hide that column if so desired. Let's say that column is "C", then in `C1` put:

```
=A1 & ":" & B1
```

Drag that formula down, and optionally hide that column.

Now, you can do the search with a simple `MATCH`:

```
=MATCH("Shoes:", $C$1:$C$6, 0)
```

For very large tables, this solution will have better performance.

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you leave a comment?